# Cut Principal Scroll-bar

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

i'm doing an app and i need help !

I made a modal window, and that modal window will be bigger than 100vh, and i need it to have an scroll-bar, and i give it a scroll bar, but the problem is that, the other main scroll-bar needs to be cut, but i jus don't know how eliminate it

[image: As you can see, it has two doble scroll-bars and i only need the one of my modal window]

Here's the css code of my modal window, i'm usign styled-components in react

```
import styles from "styled-components";

// TODO Part

export const TodoMain = styles.section`

width: 100%;
min-height 100vh;

overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;

background: white;

position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;

z-index: 100;

`;

export const Todo = styles.div`

width: 80%;
min-height: 150vh;
margin: auto;

border: 3px solid black;

`;
```

Comment: Put overflow: hidden inside the component you want to hide. Of course, you need to find it first. Inspect it using Chrome DevTool

Comment: Yes, but that container is the body of the appand i don't know how should i eliminate that when i click to make my modal window appear, because i know that is a bad practice to change the DOM in react

Comment: you may want to change style of the container or u can use ref for it.